# How to get Status of Servers in SharePoint Farm

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell

Please see this screenshot for reference

[image: screenshot]

When I say Status, I mean according to the above screenshot. Is it possible to get the status of each of the servers like this using Powershell or some other utility which can be scripted?

Thanks!

-Pranav

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean to check if the servers need to be upgraded after a patch were applied?

```
$spprod = Get-SPProduct
$spprod.Servers | select ServerName, Products, InstallStatus
```

This will give you the status for each server in your farm. If any patch are missing or a server needs to be upgraded, you can track down what patch are missing by running:

```
$spprod.Servers | ? { $_.InstallStatus -eq "InstallRequired" } | % { $_.RequiredButMissingPatches }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Christoffer! Can that `Status` (As per the screenshot) show some other values as well? Like any problems or so?

Comment: @PranavJituri The SPProduct class only has a few properties. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spproduct.aspx. I think that all the problems related to SharePoint goes directly to the logs, patching included.

Comment: But, this commandlet does not show those servers configured as an `External` role which have Search DB and other Databases used by SharePoint. Any idea how it can be done?